# Is passing "safe=true" in the mongo connection string equivalent to passing it in the callback options

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is passing Safe=true in the connection string

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDatabaseName?Safe=true", function (err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection("someCollection");
    collection.insert(item, function(err, result){
    });
}
```

equivalent to this:

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDatabaseName", function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection("someCollection");
    collection.insert(item,{safe:true}, function(err, result){
    });
}
```

Comment: dont have idea?